# Unable to use Apache Commons CLI Option.builder() in Scala

Tags: scala, maven, command-line-interface

In a spark shell or application (written in Scala/maven build), I am unable to use the static builder method from the Apache Commons CLI package.  I have confirmed that I am including the jar in the class path and have access to the `Option` class along with other classes in the package like `Options`, `DefaultParser`, etc.  Why can I not use this public static method in Scala?

```
import org.apache.commons.cli.Option

val opt = Option.builder("foo").build()
```

> error: value builder is not a member of object org.apache.commons.cli.Option

I can however see the static fields `Option.UNINITIALIZED` and `Option.UNLIMITED_VALUES`

using [commons-cli 1.3.1](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-1.3.1/org/apache/commons/cli/Option.html)

**Scala version:** 2.11.8

**Spark version:** 2.2.0

**command to start the shell:** `spark-shell --jars .m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.3.1/commons-cli-1.3.1.jar`

Comment: I am new to scala, so this will be a silly question, but Scala has access to static inner classes in java right?

Comment: Related [WordCount example - option.builder() error (intelliJ, Solr, Spark)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54293756/wordcount-example-option-builder-error-intellij-solr-spark)

Answer (score 2):

[image: Problem Source]

Let me help you clarify your problem scenario.

You can open your **.idea folder**, find that it have some internal jar dependencies already, and of the list commons_cli exists, but **1.2 version**.

This would lead to class collision.

The solution is straightforward, refer the [doc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-1.2/index.html), use the compatible constructor method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is not the case.  There is no collision with 1.2 and I am indeed using 1.3